# How to make multiple post requests, that depends on the previous ones

Tags: javascript, post, promise, axios

I need to make 5 post request, and each post depends on the id of the previous post request.

endpoint4 depends on the id of endpoint5

endpoint3 depends on the id of endpoint4

endpoint2 depends on the id of endpoint3

endpoint1 depends on the id of endpoint2

The code that i'm showing to you works, but it's too slow, make request by request taken 4s to perform the full post of the form. There is any better way to do this?

```
const data = await this.$axios
        .post('/endpoint1', {
          attr: form.somedata,
        })
        .then((res) => {
          return this.$axios.post('endpoint2', {
            attr_id: res.data.id,
            attr2: form.somedata,
          })
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log('segundo then res', res)
          return this.$axios.post('/endpoint3', {
            attr_id: res.data.id,
            attr2: somedata,
          })
        })
        .then((res) => {
          return this.$axios.post('/endpoint4', {
            attr_id: res.data.id,
            attr2: somedata,
            attr3: somedata2,
            attr4: somedata3,
            attr5: somedata4,
          })
        })
        .then((res) => {
          return this.$axios.post('/endpoint5', {
            institution: {
              attr_id: res.data.id,
              attr2: somedata,
              attr3: somedata2,
              attr4: somedata3,
            },
            attr_5: somedata4,
          })
        })
```

Comment: You could definitely format this better (since you're using `await` you don't need `then` anymore. That being said, I don't know how you speed this up other than having _fewer_ requests (if your backend can consolidate some of this logic). Nothing you do in your code will even come close to the network latency time of five requests in serial.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to wait for the result a request then you need to wait for the result of a request there is not really any way around that.

If you have control over the backend then I'd suggest checking whether there is anything there that you could reorganise (maybe merge a few endpoints into 1) but other than that there isn't really anything else I can do with the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

`GraphQL` is designed as a solution for such a problem It would get all the data in one request.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to separate the concerns and responsibility.

```js
const BASE_URL = "base url of your server";

const resolve = async (url, options) => {
    const data = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}${url}`, options)
    return await data.json() //if response will be in json format
}
```

And use combination of Resolve function and async-await to resolve result in SYNC way

```js
   const flow = async () => {
        // we destructured result and renamed it to "id1" 
        const { id: id1 } = await resolve('/endpoint1', {
            attr: form.somedata,
          });

        const { id: id2 } = await resolve('/endpoint2', {
              attr_id: id1,
              attr2: form.somedata,
            });

        const { id: id3 } = await resovle('/endpoint3', {
              attr_id: id2,
              attr2: somedata,
            })
  
        const { id: id4 } = await resovle('/endpoint4', {
              attr_id: id3,
              attr2: somedata,
              attr3: somedata2,
              attr4: somedata3,
              attr5: somedata4,
            })

        const result = await resovle('/endpoint4', {
             institution: {
              attr_id: id4,
              attr2: somedata,
              attr3: somedata2,
              attr4: somedata3,
            },
            attr_5: somedata4,
          })

      return result;
    }
```